# Who first used the shot of a character being the focus whilst walking in a large crowd?

Tags: first-appearance

In films such as *[Midnight Cowboy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064665/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)* and the [*Pursuit of Happyness*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454921/), among others. Which director used this specific shot first?

[image]

Comment: 'Being the focus' how? Can you add screenshots, maybe?

Comment: This sounds like a long lens with a wide aperture, which would restrict the depth of field - but I'd like to see pictures, even then I'm not sure how anyone would find the 'first' without some prior knowledge… but we have some good researchers on here, so you never know ;)

Comment: I've added in the shot we're probably talking about from Midnight Cowboy - yes, done on a long lens with an actor 3" or so taller than everyone around him.  Camera also elevated by the dip in the street. [It wouldn't have worked for Hoffman, as he's a foot shorter than Voight ;) From memory [haven't seen it in quite a while] they used this lens a lot for the street scenes, but rarely with this focus to the middle distance effect.